# htaccess remove index.php and param name from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have short url service for a site, which has url like `http://example.co?c=xyz`.
In index.php file parameter is being accessed as `$code = $_GET["c"];`.

I want to access the same code when i type `http://eaxample.co/xyz`

.htaccess file config

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301, L]
```

Can anyone please help me to get right rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /?c=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: For which URL it is giving 404? Make sure this is in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`

Comment: 404 for http://example.co/SAA. I am sure it is in root. I have only 2 files in root index.php and .htacess only

Comment: is `SAA` is not a file/directory then above rule will internally rewrite that to `example.com/?c=SAA` Can you load the content using `example.com/?c=SAA`?

Comment: Ok now back to basics. Are you sure .htaccess and mod_rewrite are enabled & working?

Comment: I had not added AllowOverride All in virtaulhost file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, that query string will be working you must to add **[QSA](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)** flag in yours rewriterule.

When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301, L, QSA]
```